# HAProxy health checks and changing server state

Tags: haproxy

I've poured through lots of docs and Google searches but can't seem to find an answer. I'm using HAProxy with several servers that take a while to start--initial loads on my local VM are about a minute or two. It seems from watching the debug logs that HAProxy checks these servers, fails a level 4 connection, then marks the server as permanently dead. Googling doesn't indicate a way to retrigger the health checks.

My assumption was that they'd happen again after a delay, but I don't see any notices in my logs that the servers are being rechecked. If I restart HAProxy it does detect that the servers are up, but ideally it would mark them as dead for a few minutes, detect that they're back up, then bring them back into the rotation. I've also tried sending SIGHUP but this only prints a report of the results of the last check. The config manual is a bit overwhelming. What am I missing?

Here is my haproxy.cfg:

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
  maxconn 1024
  user proxy
  group proxy
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!NULL:!aNULL:!RC4:!RC2:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!3DES
  debug

defaults
  log global
  mode http
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  option redispatch
  retries 3

  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 50s
  timeout server 50s

frontend http-in
  bind *:80
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/perceptronapp.com.pem no-sslv3
  redirect prefix https://www.perceptronapp.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i perceptronapp.com }
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  use_backend blog if { path_beg /blog }
  use_backend app

backend app
  balance leastconn
  cookie JSESSIONID insert nocache
  server s1 s1.perceptron.skydns.local:3000 check inter 3m cookie s1
  server s2 s2.perceptron.skydns.local:3000 check inter 3m cookie s2

backend blog
  server s1 s1.ghost.skydns.local:2368 check inter 3m
```

Comment: Your config looks okay, I'm not near a PC to test it right now.  But it looks like your check interval is three minutes.  Do you see anything in the logs about three minutes after startup?

Comment: Agreed, your config looks right, though depending on your use case, you might want to tweak the `inter`, `fastinter` and `downinter` settings to something a little more responsive to changes. How long are you waiting after the server comes back up before restarting HAProxy?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. HAProxy does its DNS resolution at startup, which I'd suspected but had a hard time confirming since all my queries just led me back to the config manual. Since I own the DNS infrastructure and namespace being queried (SkyDNS from Docker containers) I'd hoped to use that for service discovery and HAProxy backends. Seems like an Nginx-like resolver system may be on the HAProxy roadmap according to [this](http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?10,1070863), but a checkout and quick scan of the latest sources didn't indicate that was live yet.

Have since switched to confd-based config file generation and graceful restarts. A bit more annoying to configure but seems to do the job.