# HA proxy not recovering from "no route to host"

Tags: haproxy

We are using HA proxy in an Amazon EC2 instance to route certain requests to to two different internal load balancers which are EC2 ELBs (Elastic Load Balancers).

Here is the HA proxy configuration:

```
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    no option               redispatch
    retries                 25
    timeout connect 10000 # default 10 second time out if a backend is not found
    timeout client 30000
    timeout server 30000
    maxconn     20000
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    option http-server-close
    timeout http-request    100s
    timeout http-keep-alive 124s

backend main-service-backend
    option httpchk GET /ping
    server main-service internal-main-service:80 check inter 5s fall 10

backend micro-service-backend
    option httpchk GET /ping
    server micro-service internal-micro-service:80 check inter 5s fall 10

frontend shared-frontend *:80
    acl is-micro-service-url path_reg ^/(/rest/user/.*/?)
    use_backend micro-service-backend if is-micro-service-url
    default_backend main-service-backend
```

Normally if I shutdown one of the server for a time, HA proxy will recover.
However there seems to be some network/routing error happening and HA proxy does not recover.

Here are the HA proxy logs:

```
Server micro-service-backend/micro-service is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "No route to host", check duration: 998ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 1 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
 backend micro-service-backend has no server available!
```

HA proxy stops checking the server and keeps marking it as DOWN. However I am able to successfully do the http health check from the HA proxy box to the internal load balancer:

```
curl -i http://internal-micro-service:80/ping 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 23:08:29 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 2
Connection: keep-alive

UP
```

Any idea what might be wrong?
What else should I investigate?

Answer (score 1):

After some Googling I found that HA proxy only resolves DNS on startup.
The EC2 ELBs can randomly change IP addresses which causes the health checks to fail since HA proxy does not do DNS resolution before it does the health check.

[Elastic Load Balancers Change IP Addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821333/amazon-ec2-elastic-load-balancer-does-its-ip-ever-change)

[HA Proxy does DNS resolution on startup](https://serverfault.com/questions/669387/haproxy-health-checks-and-changing-server-state)

[More details on HA Proxy DNS resolution](http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?10,1070863)